# How to debug VBA calling Python using COM

Tags: python, pandas, excel, vba, com

I stumbled on the following blog, which contains a load of interesting VBA calls Python using COM  examples.  The first example

https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/calling-python-class-using-vba-with-com.html

works as expected.  I can make small changes to a point, accept and return variant arguments, but not much more.

A second, more involved example which uses Pandas,

https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/python-pandas-vba-return-pandas-pivot.html

fails with the following error message box (error message truncated to fit a small dialogue box)

```
Microsoft Visual Basic
Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005)
Unexpected Python Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
line 136, in CreateInstance
    return retObj._CreateInstance_(clsid, reqID)
File "C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
```

Of course, it would help to see all of this call stack.

I made some effort to duplicate what I find of the blog author's configuration, which could be
Python 3.6 with the following packages:

```
numpy           1.14.5
pandas          0.23.1   (man, that's old!)
pip             18.1
pypiwin32       223    (matches pywin32)
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pytz            2023.3
pywin32         223    (matches pypiwin32)
setuptools      40.6.2
six             1.11.0
```

I tried the same examples on a more modern configuration (Python 3.11, newer Pandas) and had the same problems.

Personally, I don't want to shell out to Python, as I have arguments to pass which shouldn't be in files.  Also, I don't want to get into xlwings or pyxll or any of those, as I have plenty of other non-VBA places which could consume Python code, so the COM approach has the most appeal.

So, I would like to understand

- what could be missing from the environment, Python or elsewhere, for COM to fail
- how would I debug where Python is running under COM

Thanks

Comment: 0x80004005 is E_FAIL which is the most generic and uinteresting error value. If the first example works, it means everything works properly on your machine (win32com, registry, bitness, etc. all checks green). If the second one fails, it probaly means something fails on python side. You'll have to find a way to debug the python code in question.

Comment: One thing I learned was to use VBS instead of VBA.  Port enough of the code you need to call Python and at least accept a variant result.  Any Python errors will display fully, not truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your COM server with the debug flag enabled, which enables logging to a shared memory buffer, which you can read using the PythonWin IDE by selecting *Tools* -> *Trace Collector Debugging Tool*.

See for example the [excelAddin.py sample program](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/8be5f45e75014ba47f628b80d75904b17c1be906/com/win32com/demos/excelAddin.py#L16-L20), which calls the [UseCommandLine function](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/8be5f45e75014ba47f628b80d75904b17c1be906/com/win32com/server/register.py#L634) to do the registration.

If you don't want to use PythonWin, you can also use the `win32trace` module to read the log buffer. The [win32traceutil](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/8be5f45e75014ba47f628b80d75904b17c1be906/win32/Lib/win32traceutil.py) module provides a convenient wrapper that you just run from the command line, e.g.: `py -3 -m win32traceutil`.

You can also use this logging facility for your own debugging messages. Importing `win32traceutil` will redirect stdout to the log buffer.

Also, I'm not sure what `pypiwin32` is, but it [looks like an empty dummy package](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/223/#files) that possibly used to be some version of pywin32. Since [pywin32 is available on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32) officially nowadays, I would just `pip install pywin32`.